# Unpack pointer to call object's method

Tags: c++

If I have the following classes:

```cpp
class Shape {
  public:
  virtual float getArea(){}
};

// A Rectangle is a Shape with a specific width and height
class Rectangle : public Shape {   // derived form Shape class
  private:
  float width;
  float height;

  public:
  Rectangle(float wid, float heigh) {
    width = wid;
    height = heigh;
  }
  float getArea(){
    return width * height; 
  }
};
```

and in the main, I call the `getArea` function like this:

```cpp
int main() {
  Rectangle r(2, 6);    // Creating Rectangle object

  Shape* shape = &r;   // Referencing Shape class to Rectangle object

  cout << "Calling Rectangle getArea function: " << r.getArea() << endl;      // Calls Rectangle.printArea()
  cout << "Calling Rectangle from shape pointer: " <<  shape->getArea() << endl; // Calls shape's dynamic-type's
}
```

My question is, why can't I unpack the pointer `shape`, which in my understanding would give a `Rectangle` object and on which I can call its `getArea` function, like this:

```cpp
cout << "Calling Rectangle from shape pointer: " <<  *shape.getArea() << endl
```

Comment: `(*shape).getArea()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, `HolyBlackCat` answered your question in his comment.

But if you are interested in "why" - check out [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

You'd see that `.   ->  Member access` has higher priority than `*a     Indirection (dereference)`. So, unless parenthesis are used, you are trying to dereference a pointer `shape` with a member access operator `.`